# Kundera-rest Usage

Tags: java, rest, kundera

I am using JPA2 entity annotations and Kundera for persistance.
I want to expose the entities to a RESTful interface.

I have understood that I can use kundera-rest to do it. I have also found an example "Kundera-Web-Examples" from [github](https://github.com/xamry/Kundera-Web-Examples).

My problem is that no matter what I try, I always end up with "404 - Not Found" when I try to use the RESTful interface.. and the logs seem very quiet...

Has anyone previous experience with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... I was not using it right.

The example "Kundera-Web-Examples" from github is wrong, or kundera-rest has changed in newer versions.